# Javascript notation. Need help understanding this declaration

Tags: javascript, object

I have inherited a block of code and I need confirmation that I'm understanding it correctly. I'm (perhaps obviously) *not* a javascript expert but I'm trying. I just need some help understanding exactly what the block of code below is doing:

```
SG_VERSION = "2.1", fss = [], allAni = {}, SG_PATH = "", sgZoom = 1, SG = function() {

  function complete() { ... }

  function Game() { ... }

  function win() { ... }

  function resize() { ... }
```

My understanding is that SG_VERSION is an 'object' with some member variables and a big method called SG, that itself has member functions?
But doesn't SG_VERSION need a 'var' somewhere?

Thanks for any insights. I appreciate any and all help however simple it may seem.

Comment: This is just a buch of global variables. (In case the *var* is missing deliberately).

Comment: SG_VERSION is global variable, those variables don't need `var` before their declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your snippet, these seem to be global variables (assuming you didn't miss out an initial `var` and that they are not declared inside an outer function() {}),

```
SG_VERSION = "2.1" // probably a string version representation
fss = [] // empty array initialization
allAni = {} // empty object initialization
SG_PATH = "" // probably to hold string values representing a PATH
sgZoom = 1 // numeric zoom level?
SG = function() {} // a function that seems to be intended for use as a class containing "private" functions complete(), Game(), win() and resize().
```

For the last variable `SG =` I think you've missed out a closing brace in your copy/paste

Comment: Even inside one or any number of functions, without the *var*, they are global. (Though there might be the case that one or all could have been declared with the *var* in one of the outer functions. In this case they are not global.) Don't know if that's what you mean in the first sentence, though.

Comment: Also I wouldn't call SG an `object`. Sure, it is an `object`, but more specifically it's a function. It's most likely meant to be called like, `SG()` or `new SG`, not used like `SG.x = 5`.

Comment: @Yoshi yeah it looks like the OP missed some things in the snippet so that's why I added that in my first line.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 Thanks! Somehow got it into my mind it was an object. Corrected it now.

Comment: Okay thanks so far! to source.rar, I *did* neglect the closing brace! In fact I neglected
        }();
which brings me to my next question: does this then mean that I'm basically defining SG as a global function attached to the window and then executing it immediately?

Comment: @b1shp if it is something like `SG = (function(){...})();` then it means that you are assigning the result of whatever that function returns to the variable `SG` which is a global (as shown in your code).

Comment: @b1shp It means you're defining an anonymous function, executing it immediately, and then storing it's return value in the global variable `SG`.

Comment: @source.rar The extra parenthesis are not necessary, `SG = function(){...}();` also will do that. The added parenthesis are only used when you want to convert a function declaration to a function expression. In this case it is already an expression, so they don't make a difference.

Comment: @b1shp It's essentially the module pattern: http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great help. Problem solved and @YTowOnt9 I'm now reading about module patterns :)

Answer (score -1):

It will be more readable if written like this:

```
var SG_VERSION = "2.1"; 
var fss = []; 
var allAni = {};
var SG_PATH = ""; 
var sgZoom = 1;

var SG = function() {...};

function complete() { ... }

function Game() { ... }

function win() { ... }

function resize() { ... }
```